# How to cURL a JAR from remote URL

Tags: java, curl

I have a JAR that is available for download from an HTTP URL, say, `http://somerepo.example.org/myjar-1.0.jar`.

I need a cURL command that will download it to the current directory; my best attempt thus far is:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/zip" -H "Content-Type: application/zip" -X GET http://somerepo.example.org/myjar-1.0.jar
```

When I run this my console fills with binary spam and seems to cause my entire terminal to have a melt down.

**What is the correct cURL command to GET a JAR from a remote URL?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are almost there. By default cURL will output the download to STDOUT. You want to redirect this to a file like so:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/zip" http://somerepo.example.org/myjar-1.0.jar > myfile.jar
```

You can also use the `-o` option:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/zip" http://somerepo.example.org/myjar-1.0.jar -o myfile.jar
```

You should also be able to use `wget`

```
wget http://somerepo.example.org/myjar-1.0.jar
```

Comment: Awesome thank you @Martin Konecny (+1) - I will give you the green check as soon as SO allows me to :-)

Comment: `wget` does the job perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Hi,i just want to download cli jar in jenkins server, using curl i will get that, but the thing i noticed  by doing less command is it has nothing in it, compared to manually downloaded content has many things in it...How can i resolve this?