# Postman unsupported format: zip

Tags: curl, postman

I'm trying to curl a zip file over to a server, using curl I have no trouble:

```
curl -v -u admin:my_password -X PUT -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @D:/Air_Quality.zip https://www.my-geoserver.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/practice/datastores/new_datastore/file.shp
```

This works fine, however using postman I select:

- Authorization: Basic Auth and put in the correct credentials
- Headers: Content-type: application/zip
- Body -> Binary: my file above

I click Send and I get:

> Unsupported format: zip

When I look at the code for the request I notice `--data-binary` and the file are missing from the code, why has postman not put them in? Would that be the problem?

The postman curl code is:

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://www.my-geoserver.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/practice/datastores/new_datastore/file.zip \
  -H 'authorization: Basic YWRtaW4AZ3VpbnwpZ2h0NzM=' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/zip' \
  -H 'postman-token: 46a7474d-2393-c7ac-8c9a-939421ae0d10'
```

Comment: A normal PUT is simpler done with `-T` instead of `--data-binary @`, and then you can remove `-X PUT` ...

Comment: Same issue occurs when trying to `GET` a ZIP File. Postman seems to stop working for minutes when ZIP File is large (e.g. 15 MB) while 'normal cURL' is fast (few seconds). Moreover, Postman response is binary in output window (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195670/how-to-curl-a-jar-from-remote-url/30195732#30195732 ).